# Why won't my street addresses georeference?

Tags: carto, geocoding, carto-js

I've been using Carto for about a month or two now and it had been working perfectly, however it suddenly malfunctioned today. I updated my excel document (nothing changed except the number of rows), uploaded it to Carto, and then analysed it for Street Addresses. For some reason the street addresses won't analyze and when I try to style the layer it says "there's no geometry in your data that could be styled".

The thing is I've updated this document about 30 times before, uploaded, analysed, and styled it and it worked every time. I had uploaded, analysed, and styled a layer about 5-10 minutes before this, so it was working fine until about 1:00pm EST. Is there anything in Carto I could have clicked that would stop it from reading the addresses correctly? The excel document is still in the same format as before, and I've uploaded files equally as large, if not larger, before so I know it's not a size thing.

Comment: Have you hit your [quota/geocoding limit](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/dataservices-api/quota-information)? Or, it may be a temporary hiccup at Carto...

Comment: I recommend sending this questions to CARTO Support.